# Print lines between two patterns through sed/AWK when there is at least one line between them

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I am trying to print lines between two patterns through sed command. But I want to include the line containing Pattern1 Pattern2 in the result when there is some line between them. If there is no line between Pattern1 and Pattern2 exclude line with Pattern1 and Pattern2 also from the file.

```
PAT1
XXX
XXX
PAT2
PAT1
XX
PAT2
PAT1
PAT2
PAT1
XXX
PAT2
```

The desired output is :

```
PAT1
XXX
XXX
PAT2
PAT1
XX
PAT2
PAT1
XXX
PAT2
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/PAT1/{b A};b B; :A {N;/PAT2/b}; :B /PAT1/,/PAT2/p'
```

When seeing PAT1, go to branch A. There, read the next line and start again if it contains PAT2. Otherwise, print the lines between PAT1 and PAT2.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^PAT1/{:a;N;/^PAT2/M!ba;/\n.*\n/p}' file
```

Collect lines between two patterns and only print if there is at least one line between the patterns.

Or:

```
sed '/^PAT1/h;//!H;/^PAT2/!d;x;/\n.*\n/!d' file
```

If a line begins with the first pattern replace whatever is in the hold space. Otherwise append the line to the hold space. If the line does not begin with the second pattern, delete it. Otherwise, swap to the hold space and delete it if there are not at least three lines.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ sed -n '/^PAT1/{N;/PAT2/d};/^PAT1/,/^PAT2/p' file
```

First, remove if `PAT1` and `PAT2` are found in consecutive lines, then print the content using `range`.

> ```
>  n N    Read/append the next line of input into the pattern space.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/PAT1/        {c=1; out=""} 
       /PAT2/ && c>2 {print out $0} 
       c&&c++        {out=out $0 ORS}' file

PAT1
XXX
XXX
PAT2
PAT1
XX
PAT2
PAT1
XXX
PAT2
```

I think it can be simplified further, but now reads as the requirements.  Start with PAT1 and aggregate lines until PAT2 and print if count of lines is more than 2.

Comment: The question was junk. Answering it just promotes more junk.